# How to filter through objects to get Result from Given (javascript)

Tags: javascript, object, filter

I need to taken what is given and print the result. How do I filter through the animals object to get the result object?

Given:

```
var animals = [
  { type: 'monkey', owner: 'Callie' },
  { type: 'rat', owner: 'Johnnie' },
  { type: 'rat', owner: 'Callie' },
  { type: 'monkey', owner: 'Megan' },
  { type: 'rat', owner: 'Megan' },
  { type: 'horse', owner: 'Megan' }
];
```

Result:

```
[
  { type: 'rat', owner: [ 'Johnnie', 'Callie', 'Megan' ], count: 3 },
  { type: 'monkey', owner: [ 'Megan', 'Callie' ], count: 2 },
  { type: 'horse', owner: [ 'Megan' ], count: 1 } 
];
```

My code is:

```
endorsements.map( function(endorsement){
    var hash = {}, users = [], count = 0, result = [], skills = endorsement.skill, skill; 

        for(var i = 0; i < skills.length; i++){
            skill = skills[i]; 
            if(!hash[skill]){
              result.push(skill); hash[skill] = true; count++; users.push(endorsement.user); 
            } 
        } 
    return {skill: skill, user: users, count: count};
 });
```

Comment: Did you try to write something yourself here?

Comment: Please review [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). This is not a code writing service. You're expected to ***have researched your issue and made a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, include a summary of what you have tried and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help with that issue.

Comment: YES - sorry, my first post on Stack Overflow...

Comment: I tried this code out and am stuck:

Comment: endorsements.map(function(endorsement){
    var hash = {},
        users = [], 
        count = 0, 
        result = [],
        skills = endorsement.skill, 
        skill;
    for(var i = 0; i < skills.length; i++){
      skill = skills[i];
      if(!hash[skill]){
        result.push(skill);
        hash[skill] = true;
        count++;
        users.push(endorsement.user);
      }
    }
    return {skill: skill, user: users, count: count};
  });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `reduce` the `animals` array and then take the `values` of the result's object:

```js
var animals = [
  { type: 'monkey', owner: 'Callie' },
  { type: 'rat', owner: 'Johnnie' },
  { type: 'rat', owner: 'Callie' },
  { type: 'monkey', owner: 'Megan' },
  { type: 'rat', owner: 'Megan' },
  { type: 'horse', owner: 'Megan' }
];

var res = Object.values(animals.reduce(function(all, item) {
  if (!all.hasOwnProperty(item.type)) {
    all[item.type] = {type: item.type, owner: [], count: 0}
  }
  all[item.type]['owner'].push(item.owner);
  all[item.type]['count']++;
  return all;
}, {}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest a different result format. If you really need the format you suggest, I think getting what I suggest as an intermediate step would make it easy.

My suggested format:

```
{
  rat: ['Johnnie', 'Callie', 'Megan'],
  monkey: ['Megan', 'Callie'],
  horse: ['Megan']
}
```

To build this format:

```
var animals = [
  { type: 'monkey', owner: 'Callie' },
  { type: 'rat', owner: 'Johnnie' },
  { type: 'rat', owner: 'Callie' },
  { type: 'monkey', owner: 'Megan' },
  { type: 'rat', owner: 'Megan' },
  { type: 'horse', owner: 'Megan' }
];

var result = {};
for (var idx = 0; idx < animals.length; idx++) {
  if (!result[animals[idx].type]) {
    result[animals[idx].type] = [];
  }
  result[animals[idx].type].push(animals[idx].owner);
}

// get some info
result['rat'].length; // 3 people own a rat
result['monkey'].indexOf('Megan'); // 1 since Megan owns a monkey
Object.keys(result); // ['rat', 'monkey', 'horse']
```